# the structure "like for somebody to do something"

Tags: grammar, syntax

I ran into this in the novel *The Old Man and the Sea*,

> “I do not like for him to waken me. It is as though I were inferior.”

What has happened in the first sentence *"I do not like for him to waken me"*?
The structure seems unfamiliar to me. Is it normal for instance to say, *"I don't like for you to leave the country"?* It seems unnatural. I normally would say, *"I don't like you to leave the country"* or *"I don't like him to wake me up"*.

Links for my further studying would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence *"I do not like for him to waken me,"* is indeed rather uncommon, but it is perfectly possible, especially in American English.

According to Swan's *Practical English Usage*, **291 infinitives (13): for ... to ...**

> **291.7 after verbs: ask for ... to ...**
>   *For*-structures are not normally used as objects after verbs.
>   [...]
>   However, verbs which are normally followed by for (e.g. *ask*, *hope*, *wait*, *look*, *pay*, *arrange*) can often be used with **for + object + infinitive**.
>   [...]
>   A few other verbs can be used like this, e.g. *suit* and *take* (*time*).
>   [...]
>   In informal American English, *like*, *hate*, *mean*, *intend* and some other verbs with similar meanings can be used with a *for*-structure. This is not usually possible in British English.
>   *I would **like for you to stay** as long as you want.*
>   *She **hates for people to feel** sad.*
>   *Did you **mean for John to mail** those letters?*

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful explanation and introducing a good reference book:) Besides, the edit you made to my question was great and I got some good points.

Comment: Thanks! So is it more common without "for"?

Comment: @Tim In standard modern English, yes. However, I think things like poems and lyrics are exceptions.