# What is the definitive difference between "wish for something" and simply "wish something"?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

I have been looking in dictionaries, and while the examples do provide some insight into the difference, I can't really derive definitive nuances specific to each option. What are they, if they exist?

Comment: We're not psychic! Tell *us* some of the examples, so we can rule on whether there's a difference, and if so what it might be. Offhand I can't think of *any* contexts where both *I wish for X* and *I wish X* could both be valid utterances, for the same value of X.

Comment: Okay - *I wish you to leave* and *I wish **for** you to leave* are both valid. They mean *exactly* the same thing - the only difference is the second version is [far less common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+you+to+leave%2Cwish+for+you+to+leave&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (And I don't like it - but obviously nor do most native speakers! :) But we'd rarely use ***wish*** there anyway. It's nearly always *I **want** you to leave*, and *I want **for** you to leave* is extremely uncommon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the structure "like for somebody to do something".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14791/the-structure-like-for-somebody-to-do-something) Also ["for" in "I like for you to be still"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15005/for-in-i-like-for-you-to-be-still)

Comment: Another option: "I wish **that** [the future is rosy] ..."