# Is this sentence grammatically correct: "The last thing he wants is for you to end up inside."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC 3 [Alcohol problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3L0Hvvfv7E). (see:9:25-9:33) It is about a man's who is tagged to get monitored if he drinks or not for a particular period of time, in which case he might be fined. So, he must stay away from alcohol. His father is already in prison for burglary, and his mother worries that he might drink and get sent to prison. He was out last night with friend and has just come home and his mother, upon finding out he actually drank, says to him:

**"Your father loves you. The last thing he wants is for you to end up inside."**

The second sentence seemed interesting to me grammatically, I thought it might not be correct, may be it is, I don't know, because according to what we were taught, the sentence structure should be;

a) **"I don't like your smoking"** or

b) **"I don't like you smoking"**,

but we never say **"I don't like for you to smoke"**, do we?

So, if we go back to the mother's sentence, I feel that the correct structure should be either:

**1- The last thing he wants is you ending up inside.** OR

**2- The last thing he wants is your ending up inside**.

So I wonder if the structure **"......for you to end up inside."** is correct and have the same meaning with the above 2 sentences?

Comment: _we never say "I don't like for you to smoke", do we?_  yes, we do.

Comment: The original sentence is fine the way it is. The trouble with your re-cast versions is … 2 is correct, but 99% of people would actually say 1 & not even *know* 2 is the correct version.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Really? Is it really correct to say "I don't like for you to smoke"? If that is true, why is it never shown on any grammar content?

Comment: See here [The structure 'I don't like for somebody to do something'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14791/the-structure-like-for-somebody-to-do-something) which quotes _Swan's Practical English Usage, 291 infinitives (13): for ... to .._

Comment: In Standard English, it is common to introduce a clause containing an infinitive with for if the verb has a subject, as where Alex comes between for and to: _I want for Alex to meet them_ [For to Infinitives (Yale University)](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/for-to-infinitives)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I looked at those pages and I am surprised to see such usages, because I did not see any of them. I now understand that what we were taught at school is limited to standard English, and is missing many other usages.

Comment: Using for (subject) to (verb infinitive) **is standard English**, as my comment above quotes Yale University. I don't like for you to smoke, I like for him to sing, I hope for you to be happy, I hate for him to shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite acceptable.

When a infinitive clause is used with an explicit subject, it it common, sometimes required for the clause to be introduce with "for".